# Ajax dosn´t Work Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My Ajax request is this, when i click on the button, send me to validarData, but never return the done ajax method.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#save').on('click', ejecturarAjax);
});

function ejecturarAjax(event)
{   
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ 
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/padron/validarData", //controller, don´t get any post data, just take the control, and never return anything.
    data: "id="+ '102030', //data what i what to get.
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "json"    
});

jqxhr.done(function(data) {
    alert(data.id);  //dosn´t work.
});

jqxhr.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert( errorThrown ); //don´t show any error.
});

jqxhr.always(function() {
    alert( 'first complete');  //don´t show the alert.
});

event.preventDefault();
};
```

index.php/padron/validarData, doesn´t retrive data from ajax:

```
class Padron extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
       //Index Page
}

public function validarData()
{

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $data["id"] = $id;

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');

    $result= json_encode( $data);

    echo $result;
}
}
```

Please, help me!!!

Comment: Tenta ``data: {'id':'102030'}``, confirma se ``base_url()`` ta retornando o valor correto, e tambem tira o ``.php`` quando vc passa o url.

Comment: No me funciona aun asì amigo, me da un error de Unexpected Token <

Answer (score 0):

declare the function name in view 
**View**

```
<button id="#save" onclick()="functionName()">Button</button>
```

Then you can use like this.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    function functionName(){
        $.ajax({    
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/padron/validarData",
            data: "id="+ '102030', 
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "json" 
          }).done(function(data){
            console.log("done");     
            //here data is the variable that contain the returned result from controller
          }).fail(function(data){
            console.log("hello fail");

          });
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i did that bro, the success method of ajax response with a unexpected tocken <, do you know why?

Comment: ajax success work in this  way. when you echo some thing in your controller that will come in the success method  and you can process on that.